# What value does Firebase Auth Identifier store from Facebook Login If user is not registered with email

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

What value does Firebase Auth Identifier store from Facebook Login If user is not registered with email but with Phone Number. My app provides facebook login but now when a user is carrying on with Facebook login my firebase auth stores the email address as an Identifiers but when someone login in my app via facebook login who had registered with phone number in facebook then my firebase auth is storing null value in Identifier. So what should I do to store a user's phone number from facebook as an identofier or facebook id as an identifier e.g id_abcd@facebook.com

Answer (score 5):

Firebase Auth backend will use the corresponding Facebook ID to identify that user. You can get the Facebook ID from the providerData list in the currentUser. There will be an entry whose `uid` is the Facebook ID. So there is no null identifier. Only the email is null.

You can also use `updateEmail` API if you want to set the email yourself on that user.

Comment: Can I get the facebook address or user name as Identifier

Comment: I assume you are using the Facebook Android SDK to sign in using a Facebook access token to Firebase. You can get all that data from the Facebook SDK.